# Invalid command when enable php-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

I can't seem to enable php fpm. The error is.

```
Invalid command ';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Which is strange, given the conf contain this.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
...
...
```

And many others, I thought semicolon here acted as comment, it seems apache mishandle this as syntax hence invalid command.

It seems there is missing plugins I need to find, anybody know the problem ?

#### Background

I'm trying to get multi PHP version to work on my server, I already build each PHP from source. I'm following this guide: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/php-multiple-versions-ubuntu

The guide tells me to add this directive to my virtual host.

> Let’s say you want to use PHP8.0 in an Apache virtual host, then open the virtual host configuration file and add the following line in the  tags.
>
> ```
> Include /etc/apache2/conf-available/php8.0-fpm.conf
> ```

And so here we are.

Comment: Looks like you’re somehow trying to include the _php-fpm_ configuration in Apache. That’s not correct. Please describe your entire setup in greater detail.

Comment: @DanielB Post edited to add my situation

Comment: So I investigated the packages in the guide. The file at `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php8.0-fpm.conf` is definitely a regular Apache 2 config file. If that’s not the case for you, something went wrong somehow and you should start from the beginning.

Comment: I build both php and php-fpm from source, could be the problem because of that ?

Comment: … so that means you are not following the guide at all. In that case, I cannot help you, sorry. All I can tell you is that you put the configuration for the PHP-FPM FCGI server where an Apache configuration file is supposed to go.

Comment: I will try to find on the web regarding this problem, thanks for your help !

Comment: @DanielB Thank you, I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to reinstall the whole thing and start from beginning , this time using ondrej PPA rather than building from source.

Everything works fine now, my only mistake was mixing PHP from package distribution and from source— creating an incompatibility.

For those who ask why I compile my own PHP, my system actually depends on old php5.5. Guess I'll try upgrade the code in order to match with newer php7.